# cat hangs randomly in .zshenv

Tags: centos, zsh

Here's what I've got in `~/.zshenv` (`/etc/zshenv` is blank)

```
print -P "before %D{%H:%M:%S}"
/usr/bin/time /bin/cat /dev/null
print -P "after %D{%H:%M:%S}"
```

If I try to start `zsh`, it will occasionally hang on the `cat` command for up to 30 seconds:

```
bash$ zsh -c exit
before 16:04:08
  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.001 total
after 16:04:29
```

If I open another new zsh immediately afterwards, the hanging never happens.  If I wait at least two minutes first, it almost always happens.

Why is this happening? How can I stop it?

This is `zsh-4.3.11` on CentOS 6.9.

Comment: Any clue from `strace -f zsh -c exit`?

Comment: Is it only `cat`? And only when passed `/dev/null`? What about `/bin/true` or `paste /dev/null`?

Comment: It originally was `cat`ing a different (empty) file, and I switched to `/dev/null` to see if the choice of file made a difference.  Looking at the output of `time` above, I think *that*'s the command that's hanging now, not `cat`.  Maybe it's the first non-native call? Originally I had multiple `cat`s, and it was always only ever the first one that hung.  I'll try `strace` when I get in Monday.

Comment: make it `strace -fTtt zsh -c exit` for timing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slowdown was due to `hash`. One of the default directories the local SAs had put in my path had 8k+ entries in it.

Using [the `strace` command suggested by  Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464717/cat-hangs-randomly-in-zshenv#comment846218_464717) revealed that the `stat()` calls used by `hash` were causing the slowdown.

If I opened another shell immediately afterwards, the each `stat()` call was up to 180x faster (presumably due to caching), which explains why the slowdown didn't happen every time.

As a fix, I removed the directory from my `PATH`. If I need any executables from there, I'll just put symlinks to them in a smaller directory in my `PATH`.